# Receive packages from Amazon.de while in Germany for 3 weeks (Tourist)

Tags: germany, tips-and-tricks, mail

I'm going to Germany for 3 weeks in December. While I'm there I'd like to order a few things off Amazon.de and have them delivered at the place I'm staying in (it's a paid apartment and the owners are not around). Can I sign up in Amazon.de and set the shipping address to the place I'm living in? Will I be able to receive packages etc.?

Comment: Why not? Just add your name, c/o the family name of the owners, and the complete address.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mail order services which are not particular to traveling/travelers.

Comment: In my opinion it deserves to stay open, at least till it has got a good answer. Being abroad as a tourist, in the house of other people, makes for a different situation than using mail shopping at home.

Comment: @Flimzy This _is_ specific to travelling people. If you don't travel, you don't need to ask this question.

Comment: I agree with @Willeke, *except* for the part "at least till it has got a good answer". Either, a question needs to be closed and thus will not be "treated" here, or it needs to stay open. Closing only once a good answer is there would be equivalent to saying that the site is open to all kinds of questions and will provide answers to any topics, just that some of them will be marked as "off-topic". I think that is not in the spirit of closing questions, as it would not provide a motivation for askers to ask in the right place and instead clutter search results on Travel SE.

Comment: @yo': Asking if Amazon can ship to a given address is specific to travel?

Comment: @Flimzy Asking if Amazon can ship to an address where I don't live, my name is not on the mailbox and I may be a foreigner there -- yes, that's something one doesn't encounter unless he moves is ass out of his warm chair at home.

Comment: @yo': Or if he's shipping gifts to friends or relatives.

Comment: i ship everything i order to my mother who has another surname. never had a problem. you can even send presents to some1 else.

Comment: I mostly ship to my workplace if I expect the stuff urgently and don't want to wait until either I'm home at the same time as my neighbours or have time to collect from the nearest post office. So delivery to myself c/o somewhere else is very commonplace for me ...

Comment: @A`: Indeed. Which is why this doesn't seem like a travel question at all.

Comment: @Flimzy: Seeing that various answers point out to have the parcel sent to a PackStation, when the chipcard for a PackStation is only available to residents of Germany, it seems clear that this question has some travel-specific complications.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: If that's true, then the wrong answer was accepted, because that answer is about the US, where there is absolutely nothing travel-specific required.

Comment: @Flimzy: The answer uses a U.S. address as an example for how to use "c/o". It will work the same in Germany and many other countries that respect semi-international conventions such as "c/o" in an address.

Comment: A Germany-specific question: in the US, many mail/post boxes are locked. If a package is too large, and you're in an apartment building, a key to a larger mailbox might be left in the regular box. Could this happen in Germany? Or another circumstance where the package is delivered but is inaccessible due to not having access to the regular mailbox? Or, what if the owners have put a hold (do-not-deliver) order in?

Comment: @mkennedy: I have never heard about that system with keys. Normally, mailboxes are indeed locked in an apartment building, in a way that only the holder of the key can open them to retrieve anything that has been put into the mailbox through the slot. For anything that is too large, the postman will ring and try to hand over the parcel, or whatever it is, personally. If the recipient is not at home, they might try ringing at some neighbours' flats and ask someone else to take the parcel, or else take it back to the post office from where the recipient can fetch it within a week or so. ...

Comment: ... In both of the latter cases, the postman is supposed to leave a card in the recipient's mailbox that informs them where the parcel is. It is true that if you have someone send something to your temporary location, but do not have any way to access the mailbox (no key, no contact to owners), you won't be able to get your piece of mail. As for the hold order, that might turn out differently (smaller post stations might well be informed by the owners that certain letters addressed at the guest should be delivered, while post offices in large cities will probably offer no such exceptions). ...

Comment: ... For anything more concrete, I suggest asking on [Expatriates SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Last time I was in this situation I was careful enough to include the name of the house owner to the destination address [(that's what c/o is for)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/c/o), so that the postman knows where to ring/in whose post box to place the package. Something like this will work:

```
John Doe
c/o Addams Family
0001 Cemetery Lane
Chicago, US
```

For completeness sake, the equivalent of c/o in German is p.Adr. which would result in:

```
John Doe
p.Adr. Addams Family
0001 Cemetery Lane
Berlin, Germany
```

Comment: While it will work, there is no reason to use English abbreviations in German postal addresses.

Comment: @CarstenS So what would be the German equivalent?

Comment: c/o will be understood, if German is preferred, the equivalent is p.Adr. ("per Adresse").

Comment: FWIW, I've never even once seen "p.Adr." in Germany, and I personally wouldn't have understood it w/o this answer, but c/o is used frequently.

Answer (score 9):

It is not exactly clear why it's on travel but just write your name and the address on it, it's not like the postman is going to run a check against the land registry to see whether the package is addressed to the owners and refuse to deliver if not. When I was in Germany in a similar situation in 2007 I had zero problems receiving packages, including a laptop mailed from Japan. Can't imagine the situation changing materially since.

However, if you are worried then Germany has a ton of pickup locations, check [About Pickup Locations for Amazon Deliveries](http://www.amazon.de/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200787040) for more.

Comment: "ton of pickup locations" - maybe, but some of them (at least those closely working with or run by DHL) require a DHL customer account (Postnummer), which again might be difficult to obtain from abroad.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper why? Enter your name + address, done...?

Comment: If you enter your address, we're back at the problem of how to receive something while not at home, right? I'm not sure whether the post company will send the chipcard to addresses abroad, and when I signed up, if I remember correctly, the letter with the chipcard arrived *some time* in the course of a month. That is, the OP might not be able to time the receipt of that letter to be exactly during the 3 weeks of their stay in Germany.

Comment: My first reaction on reading the Q was: As long as the package will arrive when you are there, not any later. As I did not have good advice about it I did not answer.

Comment: I recently had to replace my DHL chip card. They promised 14 days, but it took them at least three weeks. Hermes Paketshop is an option, but you will have to show some ID to retrieve your package.

Comment: Reference for my above remarks: [DHL's FAQ](https://www.dhl.de/en/paket/pakete-empfangen/packstation/faq.html) says for getting a free chipcard, you must "be resident in Germany". While they might or might not check actual residency (by requesting a copy of the residence registration), it is unlikely they will send the chipcard to a foreign address when it's only available to people with a German address, anyway.

Comment: Last time I did the Packstation card with someone, it required printing a PostIdent form and going to a post office to show ID _before_ they started producing the card (which is a magnet stripe card, there is no chip on it). Packstation is not a viable solution for a short stay. Regular mail is. Amazon sends DHL or Hermes. Hermes might end up a Paketshop (Kiosk, local store, whatever) near your address or a neighbour. DHL will end up either with a neighbour or in the post office where you need to show ID to pick it up next day. Always put your real name.

Comment: @simbabque: DHL *might* also end up in a PackStation for which you get a sheet of paper with a barcode that the PackStation can scan. You don't need a registration for this method, however you cannot directly request this type of delivery to a PackStation.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that one I have not seen. Good to know. As a registered customer you can configure it to go to Packstation if you're not home.

Answer (score 5):

As Aleksandr mentioned, the first step is to convince Amazon to try and ship to a new address. When I tried things like that, the **Amazon** site asked additional verification questions before they shipped it.

Amazon will then give the parcel to **DHL**. There are some reports how DHL subcontractors are under extreme time pressure and will not spend much time to resolve problems if nobody answers the bell or if they can't find your name on the door. If they can't deliver the parcel, it goes to a **Deutsche Post** office and the recipient gets notified. (If they find the address but nobody answers the bell, they might give the parcel to a neighbour and put a note into the mailbox.)

In the post office, you will have to identify yourself before they hand the parcel over. There *could* be a hitch if you can't show that you're living at the address, or if they haven't seen that kind of ID before.

The suggestion of a c/o address sounds sensible, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that if no-one picks up the parcel from the post office (and no-one has asked them beforehand to store persons for a particular recipient), it will automatically be returned to the sender after a week or so.

Comment: I'm doing c/o all the time for sending stuff to work and for putting nicknames on post cards as well as parcels. German postal services like DHL, Hermes, Deutsche Post, GLS and DPD all know how to deal with that. Also see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zustellanweisung#Bei_Unter-_oder_anderen_Mietern

Comment: @simbabque, there is a difference between a parcel where someone has to sign and a plain postcard.

Comment: @o.m. I know. That's why I mentioned both. Ordering stuff from Amazon to your workplace using `Max Mustermann\nACME GmbH` is totally fine and both DHL as well Hermes will handle it. The same you can put `o.m.\nc/oMustermann` on a postcard. Both will arrive perfectly fine. :)

Answer (score 5):

A solution to several of the problems raised in the other answers might be to contact your hosts and arrange with them that you can order the item to arrive before you do, (if they live there and are willing to accept it for you or at their home address where they can arrange for it being delivered or collected.) I am sure many hosts will do, maybe at a small charge.

If the online seller is giving you a hard time, your host might even do the actual ordering but in that case you may have to send them the money before they order, that requires more trust than just accepting a package.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use amazon.de for ordering goods, one option is to not use your address at all and to have your goods delivered to a **Hermes Paketshop**. During checkout, the Amazon website will allow you to select one and shows its opening times. If you select this option, you will receive an e-mail when your delivery is at the Paketshop and then you can collect it from there during its opening times.

In many major cities, there are gas stations with pretty good opening times (e.g., 6:00-22:00) available as Paketshops. You need some form of ID (e.g., passport) to collect your items.

The advantage of taking this route is that you don't risk your package being delivered to the neighbour in case you are absent when the postman comes. Depending on the neighbours, the packet can be tricky to collect, especially if you don't speak German. Alternatively, the package can be taken to the next post office, which may have inconvenient opening times (some close at noon-ish on Saturdays, for example). Also, the Hermes Packshop has the advantage over the DHL Packstation that you don't need to register in advance (and thus do not have to wait for a couple of weeks for your Packstation card to arrive).

Answer (score 4):

Amazon has unified accounts for their sites in various countries many years ago. If you have an Amazon.com account then you can use Amazon.de with the same account (not sure if you still have to do a registration step the first time you use it). You can specify an arbitrary delivery address. If you want to test that, you can buy me a gift :)

Answer (score 2):

The real concern is avoiding tripping fraud prevention mechanisms. Given the amount of hacking that is going on lately, many organizations are on a hair trigger. Warning flags for them are shipping address being different from billing, credit card being used for online purchases in a different country, brand new online account created, package being sent to a hotel, etc.

I've noticed Amazon in general is fairly lax about fraud prevention, and you should continue using your account on amazon.de instead of registering a new one. You should notify your bank, but often the problem is not with them (since the store and its credit card processor carries the cost of fraud as well). So, your luck will depend on the store you order from. Shopping in a physical store has higher chances of success.

Comment: "Warning flags for them are shipping address being different from billing" - this claim sounds questionable to me, given that the whole point of separately asking for a shipping address and a billing address is to enter different values there. Also, at least in Germany, with services like PackStation (that only accept parcels), receiving parcels at a different address than the bill (sometimes sent separately as a letter) is commonplace.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Well, if you were a thief, you wouldn't send the package to the person receiving the bill, now would you? Perhaps I should have said "new address." However, if you're shopping at a new online store every address that isn't the billing address is equally "new." Of course people may want to ship to various addresses, but it's still a warning flag.

Comment: If you were a thief, you wouldn't care a lot about what happens to the bill; you could just as well receive it along with the parcel if you don't intend to pay it, anyway (it's not like your current address would be kept secret otherwise, as you still use it as the delivery address). In fact, sending the bill to someone else might draw unnecessary attention and alert someone something fishy is going on. Also note that a lot of online parcels work by either paying upon ordering, or paying to the delivery service upon delivery. In these cases, the "billing address" is merely the address ...

Comment: ... that's printed on the bill, not the address where the money is actually collected from.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky You seem to be claiming that asking for billing and shipping addresses separately is some sort of trick question designed to catch fraudsters. It's not. It's a non-trick question designed to allow you to send things to anyone you want, anywhere you want.

Comment: Amazon may ask you to re-enter your credit card information rather than use a stored payment method when you enter a new address. But it is not a problem for them.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In the US, the "billing address" is not used to send an invoice (personal purchases), it is only used to verify the credit card data.

Comment: @DavidRicherby No, it isn't a trick question. It is of course useful. However, banks and websites are more cautious with purchases for which they do not match.

Comment: @Calchas Yes, Amazon works well. Other stores... not so much.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: I see. That is probably different in Germany, given that I often enter a different billing address than what the credit card company knows, at least when booking hotel rooms. I'm not sure whether or why hotel booking sites would act differently in this respect than online stores. Come to think of it, I did the same in Canada.